# is it possible to pass template variable to django template tag

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I created a custom django template tag and it accepts few arguments. Now the problem I am facing is that, the argument that would be passed to template is dynamic and dependent on the value passed from view function.

suppose template has value arg1 and I want to pass it to template tag, so I do like

`{% custom_tag {{arg1}} %}`

but it doesn't interpret arg1 as variable but a string, any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly is. Take a look at the docs for [simple tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags)

They provide the following example of a tag which takes a string to format the time;

```py
import datetime
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def current_time(format_string):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(format_string)
```

```html
{% current_time "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p" as the_time %}
<p>The time is {{ the_time }}.</p>
```

When you provide an argument, you don't need to use the curly braces, so your example would be done as `{% custom_tag arg1 %}`

Comment: I am using inclusion tag, I have already tried without curly braces still it thinks my variable is a string

Comment: works with simple tag though, saved my day :)

Comment: @dococoj ah inclusion tags use a template of their own to build context and render that template into the place you add the tag so that's different. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags